# Any notification or observer for 'Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue'?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

In my app, I'm downloading some videos and after some time device memory is getting full and due to which app is getting terminated by OS with the message,

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

on console.
It is ok with app is getting terminated but as per user perspective, user is not able recognise the reason behind abruptly termination.

So before app gets terminate I want to show the message something like 'Low memory'.

And my concern is, is there any mechanism or notification to check if memory is getting full on which we
 can show the alert?

```
Support: Swift 3.0, Xcode 8.3, iOS 10.x
```

Comment: If your app gets terminated due to a memory issue, your code most probably has a memory leak that should be fixed.

Comment: It's not a memory leak issue. I just want to display a warning message for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method.

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

Comment: Yes! That's it... But almost all the view controllers I implemented in app, calling this API but no callback is coming in the method. Strange!

Comment: Try to use device or enable the memory warning in the Simulator by following
 Hardware > Simulate Memory Warning and see what happens.

Comment: Using device only. It happens on device with low storage (currently having around 500MB free). I mean issue will be occurred on low storage device. So before app termination, it would be good experience to show at least warning message to user right?

Answer (score 0):

Try below post notification observer.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
    self?.removeAllObjects() // write your memory release code.
}
```